# Adding SSL to Azure Blob Static Site

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-static-website-hosting

I created a **Static Site** in Azure Blob storage and hosted my angular application. The **https** is working fine when I access the root site. When I access any route, I get an **https** error. It says the site is suspicious.

- How can I fix this issue?
- Does Azure Blob storage provide shared SSL
  to be used for the Static Site?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Azure Blob storage doesn't provide shared SSL.

**You can try mapping with https by Azure CDN.**

TLS would be deployed just by **CDN managed**.

[image]

My [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website)